# Lookup Closest Value in Range (Includes Negative Values)

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to lookup up the closest match to decimal values between -1 and 1 in the range:

1 | 0.5 | 0 | -0.5 | -1

A `VLOOKUP()` won't work as it doesn't function when lookup up negative values. I've tried looking up the problem on Google and on this forum, but have yet to find the solution.

```
Lookup Range  Return Values
1             5
0.5           4
0             3
-0.5          2
-1            1
```

When I try to lookup these values the results in Google Sheets are as follows:
Lookup Formula: `=VLOOKUP(Lookup Value,Lookup Range,2,TRUE)`

```
Google Sheets
Lookup Value   Return Value
 0.1           1
-0.8           #N/A
 0.9           1
-0.5           #N/A
 0.4           1
```

When I try the same in Excel the results are:

```
Excel
Lookup Value   Return Value
 0.1           #N/A
-0.8           #N/A
 0.9           1
-0.5           #N/A
 0.4           #N/A
```

The desired result is:

```
Lookup Value   Return Value
 0.1           4
-0.8           2
 0.9           5
-0.5           2
 0.4           4
```

Comment: What is the formula you are using.  The forth criteria should be `TRUE` and the lookup table should be sorted on the lookup range in ascending order

Comment: =VLOOKUP(Lookup Value,Lookup Range,2,TRUE)
Will include it in the post as well

Comment: Then sort the lookup range on the first column in ascending order `-1,-0.5,0,...`

Comment: It worked, thanks! Can't believe the solution was that simple

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(L2:L6, SORT(I2:J6), 2))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The problem with VLOOKUP is that it always returns the lower value.